# Etymology of "cronyism"

Tags: etymology, nouns

*Cronyism* probably comes from Greek *khronios* ("long-lasting") which has a sense of "old friend". But how is it connected with today's meaning?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crony agrees. But that *is* today's meaning, isn't it? Old friend => someone one does a favour for => someone one might employ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we have etymology from etymonline.com:

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cronyism+&searchmode=none

And
from Wikipedia we also have this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronyism

And you can fine some extensive definition here:

> Cronyism is partiality to long-standing friends, especially by
>   appointing them to positions of authority, regardless of their
>   qualifications. Hence, cronyism is contrary in practice and principle
>   to meritocracy. Cronyism exists when the appointer and the beneficiary
>   are in social contact; often, the appointer is inadequate to hold his
>   or her own job or position of authority, and for this reason the
>   appointer appoints individuals who will not try to weaken him or her,
>   or express views contrary to those of the appointer. Politically,
>   "cronyism" is derogatorily used. The word "crony" first appeared in
>   18th century London, believed by many to be derived from the Greek
>   word χρόνιος (chronios), meaning "long-term", however, crony appears
>   in the 1811 edition of Grose's Vulgar Tongue with a decidedly
>   non-collegiate definition, placing it firmly in the cant of the
>   underworld. A less likely source is the Irish Language term
>   Comh-Roghna (pron. ko-ronə), which translates to "close pals", or
>   mutual friends. Governments are particularly susceptible to
>   accusations of cronyism, as they spend public money. Many democratic
>   governments are encouraged to practice administrative transparency in
>   accounting and contracting, however, there often is no clear
>   delineation of when an appointment to government office is "cronyism".
>   It is not unusual for a politician to surround him- or herself with
>   highly-qualified subordinates, and to develop social, business, or
>   political friendships leading to the appointment to office of friends,
>   likewise in granting government contracts. In fact, the counsel of
>   such friends is why the officeholder successfully obtained his or her
>   powerful position — therefore, cronyism usually is easier to perceive
>   than to demonstrate and prove. In the private sector, cronyism exists
>   in organizations, often termed 'the old boys club' or 'the golden
>   circle', again the boundary between cronyism and 'networking' is
>   difficult to delineate. Moreover, cronyism describes relationships
>   existing among mutual acquaintances private organizations where
>   business, business information, and social interaction are exchanged
>   among influential personnel. This is termed crony capitalism, and is
>   an ethical breach of the principles of the market economy; in advanced
>   societies, crony capitalism is a breach of market regulations, e.g.
>   the Enron fraud is an extreme example of crony capitalism. Given crony
>   capitalism's nature, these dishonest business practices are frequently
>   (yet not exclusively) found in societies with ineffective legal
>   systems. Resultantly, there is an impetus upon the legislative branch
>   of a government to ensure enforcement of the legal code capable of
>   addressing and redressing private party manipulation of the economy by
>   the involved businessmen and their government cronies.

For more information you can see:

http://crony.askdefine.com/